# wifi connection always on, dns stops working, no entries in journalctl, where else can i look?

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, dns, systemd

Periodically the wifi stops working. The only way i can get it working again is to manually turn off wifi in KDE and turn it back on again. It automatically connects to the previous wifi spot and all is good. However this does not happen everywhere and not all the time. Also when i had windows on the box i did not have this issue. Also with previous version of Ubuntu it did not occur either.

Tailing the logs using sudo journalctl -f does not show anything relevant.

Where else could i look for any clues?

Thanks

```
Ubuntu 19.04

*-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                logical name: wlp3s0
                version: 01
                serial: 60:d8:19:c3:c5:16
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192ce driverversion=5.0.0-15-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.29 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                resources: irq:17 ioport:5000(size=256) memory:f2400000-f2403fff
```

Comment: Something related to power management maybe?